# How to replace line end with a comma in VIM?

Tags: vim

```
ab
cd
ef
```

For each line in my text file, I want to put them all in one line, delimited with a comma:

```
ab,cd,ef
```

I tried with:

```
%s/$/,/g
```

It inserted the comma, but still line count doesn't change. How to do that in vim?

I changed it to

```
%s/\n/,/g
```

And it worked.

Comment: If `%s/\n/,/g` worked for you, then what is your question?

Answer (score 13):

There are many ways to achieve that:

#### `@` register:

In normal mode, press <kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>@</kbd>
<kbd>=</kbd>
<kbd>'</kbd>
<kbd>A</kbd>
<kbd>,</kbd>
<kbd>CTRL-V</kbd>
<kbd>ESC</kbd>
<kbd>J</kbd>
<kbd>'</kbd>
<kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### `:s` command:

```
%s/\n/,/|s/,$//
```

#### "Join" plugin

I wrote a vim plugin https://github.com/sk1418/Join, which can join lines with separator. In this case, you can do:

```
:%J ','
```

And the plugin allows you do many other things with line-join in vim.